# how to make a table that does not alter in size in html

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, dreamweaver

high guys i want to make a 2 rowed 3 columned table or structure similar that does not alter in width or height no matter what i put into it. at the moment when my table is created. the top row is for 3 titles and the bottom row is for descriptions of the titles but the arrangement is not neat as the text keeps altering the size of the table. hence making it not look symmetrical. i have tried giving the width and height length percentages but the structure is still altered with text. I would like to create a solid frame. Can you help me?

Comment: did you try table { table-layout: fixed; }

Comment: @Danield fixed layouts will still have cells that expand to wrap their content, see: http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/fz4mp/

Comment: You have not said anything about whether your table is fixed width and fixed height or responsive (% lengths).  Also, it may be that you want the three columns to be of equal width, which is a easier problem to solve.  Put more effort into writing a more detailed description and you may get a few good answers.  Also, post your code and CSS, people tend to like to see what you tried.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/fz4mp/3/)**

```
table 
{ 
  table-layout: fixed; 
    width: 100%;
}
th, td 
{ 
  height: 100px; /*whatever you need */
  break-word: word-wrap; /* prevent td's to stretch to fit long words */
}
```

Comment: As you vary the width of the view port in the fiddle, the table cells adjust their widths!  That is what they do!

Comment: Trying to fixed the height and width of a table is like herding cats, very frustrating!

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td style="height: 50px; width: 100px; border: 1px solid black;">
            <div style="height: inherit;">
                Title 1 Title 1  Title 1  Title 1  Title 1  Title 1  Title 1  Title 1  Title 1 
            </div>
        </td>
        <td style="height: 50px; width: 100px; border: 1px solid black;">
            <div style="height: inherit;">
                Title 2 Title 2  Title 2  Title 2  Title 2  Title 2  Title 2  Title 2  Title 2 
            </div>
        </td>
        <td style="height: 50px; width: 100px; border: 1px solid black;">
            <div style="height: inherit;">
                Title 3 Title 3  Title 3  Title 3  Title 3  Title 3  Title 3  Title 3  Title 3 
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="height: 50px; width: 100px; border: 1px solid black;">
            <div style="height: inherit;">
                Description 1 Description 1  Description 1
            </div>
        </td>
        <td style="height: 50px; width: 100px; border: 1px solid black;">
            <div style="height: inherit;">
                Description 2 Description 2  Description 2
            </div>
        </td>
        <td style="height: 50px; width: 100px; border: 1px solid black;">
            <div style="height: inherit;">
                Description 3 Description 3  Description 3
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

But it may cause your tables to look like this when you put in too much data or text that is too long:
[image]

EDIT: According to Marc Audet, and this actually looks nice:
[image]

Comment: If you set `overflow: auto` or `overflow: hidden` on the `div` wrappers, that would take care of the problem.

Comment: Yes, I have added a screenshot how it looks like when you use Marc's advice:)

Answer (score 0):

Here is sample table that have fixed structure

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

    <title>Table</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        #gradient-style
        {
            width: 100%;
            text-align: left;
            border-collapse: collapse;
            table-layout: fixed;
            text-align: center;
            border: 1px solid black;
        }
        #gradient-style th
        {
            padding: 6px;
            width: auto;
        }
        #gradient-style td
        {       
            text-align: center;
            vertical-align: middle; 
            height: 20px;
            border: 1px solid black;
        }

    </style>
   </head>
   <body>
   <table id="gradient-style" cellspacing="0">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th scope="col">Column 1</th>
                <th scope="col">Column 2</th>
                <th scope="col">Column 3</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Row 1</td>
                <td>Row 1</td>
                <td>Row 1</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Row 2</td>
                <td>Row 2</td>
                <td>Row 2</td>
            </tr>

        </tbody>
         <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="3">Table description goes here....</td>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
      </table>
   </body>
</html>
```